# OSError in creating folder in a user given path PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-os

I am having a function in which I want to get a path from the user as input and I want to create a folder in the path.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import os
import datetime

def create_folder(name)
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    folder_name = str(name)+"_("+str(current_time)+")_DATA"
    parent_dir = directory_var.get()        #getting value from tkinter
    print(folder_name)
    print(parent_dir)
    path = os.path.join(parent_dir, folder_name)
    os.mkdir(path)

create_folder("John")
```

The output with error I am getting is :

```
John_(2021-08-05 23:43:27.857903)_DATA
C:\app_testing

os.mkdir(path)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 
'C:\\app_testing\\John_(2021-08-05 23:43:27.857903)_DATA'
```

I need to create a new folder or directory in the given parent_dir with folder name as John_(date)_DATA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem may be the colons?  See [Windows file/path naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions).  Specifically,

```
Use any character in the current code page for a name, including 
Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set 
(128–255), except for the following:

The following reserved characters:

< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

If you reformat your date to replace the `:` that could solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import os
import datetime
from time import strftime


def create_folder(name):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    x = current_time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H.%M.%S')  # You choose the format!
    folder_name = str(name)+"_("+str(x)+")_DATA"
    parent_dir = directory_var.get()  # getting value from tkinter
    print(folder_name)
    print(parent_dir)
    path = os.path.join(parent_dir, folder_name)
    os.mkdir(path)


create_folder("John")
```

Comment: Forward slashes are just as bad as colons from a Windows perspective.

Comment: As I said: 'You choose the format!'; maybe I wasn't clear enough

Comment: Yes, you did, but novices have a way of blindly pasting code without bothering to read such comments. Better not to wrong-foot a beginner by presenting an example you know (or ought to know) won't work. OP would not have asked the question if he knew about the rules for Windows filenames.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear that the answer was just an example of what he could do to change the format; thanks for the answer!